# DaVinci Resolve Fusion working when I add one node but as soon as i add another node it crashes

Tags: crash

DaVinci Resolve Fusion working when I add one node but as soon as I add another node it crashes.

Graphics card AMD Radeon RX 570 Series

here is the image of it after I add two fusion nodes that yellow box is the node that I tried to add and it crash
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/djQuu.png

Comment: This is not at all Ubuntu related. Please visit a DaVinci Resolve forum for support of such a very specialized software.